How to put a seperate animation onto an already rigged character?
I was wondering if someone could help me. You see, I have rigged up a 3d character and all and it works pretty well, but what I am trying to do now is put animations on that said rig.
So what I did was went to Mixamo and got myself a no-skin character animation (basically just the rig), but my problem is that I have no idea how to put that animation onto my already existing rig that I made for my character earlier

Is your 3d character rig a Mixamo rig or a Blender armature?

The easiest way would be to upload your character (without an armature) to Mixamo and get Mixamo to rig it for you. There's a tutorial for Blender 4.2 here whcih includes downloading and applying Mixamo animation sequences to your rigged model.

It's a blender armature and I have uploaded it to Mixamo, but it seems to not work when I redownload it afterwards. none of the animations are there. What is your opinion on Rokoko?
Thanks!

I'm not sure you can use a Blender armature in Mixamo. Never used Rokoko and that's off-topic here (as is Mixamo to be honest.)
